# Permutation gem

Tags: ruby, permutation, ruby-1.8

I am trying to get a list of strings that are permutations of letters, numbers and the dash that vary in length from 1 to 63.
I am using the permutation gem, and trying to get strings with `join('')`.

```
length = 1
alphabet = [('a'..'z').to_a, ('0'..'9').to_a, ('-').to_a].flatten
while length < 64
  puts (alphabet.permutation(length){|x| p x}).join('')
  length += 1
end
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
["r", "q", "l"]
["r", "q", "m"]
```

I am sure I am missing something fundamental here.
Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: `p` returns `nil`, by the way, so `puts (nil).join('')` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Yep, it does work...

    "file--53.txt"
    "file--54.txt"

However, I am trying to get rid of the "p" in the block and assign that whole string to a instance variable and then enter into a db.

Comment: Btw, you are not using the permutation gem here :P It's just ruby >= 1.8.7

Comment: LOL! Thank you for the heads up, so downloading the permutation gem was a waste of time as well as reading up on it.

Comment: Answered my own question...

Took out the block and broke it down into a .each do |x|, etc.

Thank you all for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. What about the following code (a simplified example):

```
['a','b','c'].permutation(3).collect { |x| x.join('')}
```

Returning,

```
=> ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... how would one assign the output of the join to a variable...

I am trying {|x| @variable = x.join('')} but it is not giving me what I want.

Comment: @perm_or_not_to_perm Do you want to store the whole array ? If so try `@variable = ['a','b','c'].permutation(3).collect { |x| x.join('')}`

Answer (score 1):

So let's make SQL query with this mechanism:

Let's say I want to find a person in database. Person has Firstname and Lastname, instead of just 'Name'. To make it more complicated, either Firstname and Lastname may contain many words.

... so we have query string from our search engine, containing "Jo Svenda Schmidt" , where "Jo Svenda" is Firstname.

```
query = "Jo Svenda Schmidt".split
=> ["Jo", "Svenda", "Schmidt"]
query.permutation(query.length).collect { |x| x.join(" AND ") }.join(" OR ")

=> "Jo AND Svenda AND Schmidt OR Jo AND Schmidt AND Svenda OR Svenda AND Jo AND Schmidt OR Svenda AND Schmidt AND Jo OR Schmidt AND Jo AND Svenda OR Schmidt AND Svenda AND Jo"
```

This is almost what we want, but not all. We need to add column names and group it.
grouping may be simple, just
    ... join(" ) OR ( ") 
at the and, and then add "(" to the beginning and ")" to the end of resulting query.

But how to add nicely 'Firstname=' and 'Lastname=' or 'LIKE' to this query?